# how can i open a link without using "http" info..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

In my app, I have a field to fill by my user for their URL. After they fill I convert the url into a href link. But sometimes user does not add a `http://` prefix to their link, so a link is not working properly..

Is there any way to open a link even without the `http://` prefex in the href?

If anyone knows the way without using javascript is fine, else we can try with javascript.

Here is my

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

<br>

<a target="_blank" href="http://google.com">Google</a>

<br>

<a target="_blank" href="www.google.com">Google</a> // this is not work!
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/HTjeN/1/)

Comment: You have to specify the protocol for the link. So you'll have to use either `http://`or `https://` depending what the site can handle.

Comment: `$('a:not([href^="http:"]):not([href^="//"])').attr('href', function () {
    return "//" + $(this).attr('href')
});`  http://jsfiddle.net/HTjeN/3/

Comment: How do you 'convert the url into a href link'?

Comment: The only alternative i'm aware of is `<a target="_blank" href="//www.google.com">Google</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should force the user to insert a valid url, for instance by using a proper `inpout` tag:

```
<input type="url" placeholder="Enter a valid URL - e.g. http://path.to/website">
```

In case you can't/you don't want to edit existing content

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').click(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
  window.location = /^(http|https):/.test(this.href) ? this.href : 'http://' + this.href;

});
```

Comment: It's ok. But i thought I might get some solution without using JS.

Comment: @3gwebtrain you cannot, because all non-proper URLs are considered relative to current webroot ^^

Comment: thanks, can you tell me why this is not work.. var link = $("a").attr("href");
console.log ( link.match('/^(http|https)/') ); i suppose to get true or false right..?

Comment: @3gwebtrain you should not enquote the regexp, it works with `/` as delimiters. If you write `/^(http|https):/.test(someUrl)` in your browser console, it will work!

Comment: For the record: I don't think this is a good solution. The OP wrote that he is 'converting the url into a link' but he doesn't elaborate how he does that. IMO the check should be done in the conversion process, not afterwards when a user clicks on a link. Without knowing how the OP converts the urls this question cannot be answered.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I do agree, that's why I proposed to validate input _before_ displaying it, the JS thing is just a workaround - about OP statement, I am pretty sure he means the converts URL into the shown markup, with no other interaction whatsoever - but he only may clarify ^^